# ActionBar CustomView won't be centered

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I have some screens with different actionBar layouts and try to center the title of each actionBar. This is my layout:

actionbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Control"
        android:textColor="@color/fragment_title_font"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTitle"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonActionbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/button_actionbar"
        android:text=""
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the code to show my custom actionBar:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null),
    new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        Gravity.CENTER
));
```

if the screen has no right button and only left UpButton, it looks fine:
[image]

if the screen has no left UpButton but right button, it looks fine too:
[image]

but if I want to set both, my title is not centered more:
[image]

Is there any possibility to center my title in all cases?

EDIT: the suggestion of @tynn works only for my third case. Better then nothing, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is centered in all your cases, just the buttons are overlaying. If you want to center the `TextView` relative to the button you need to make the layout definitions relative to the button instead of centering it relative to the parent layout.

One possible way to achieve your goal by using a `LinearLayout` (doing the same with a `RelativeLayout` should be straightforward but a little more verbose)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Control"
        android:textColor="@color/fragment_title_font"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonActionbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/button_actionbar"
        android:text=""
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If doing so you, shouldn't set the `LayoutParams` explicitly and if you do don't use `ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` for the width

```
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: see my EDIT. In your case my right button is not more on the right

Comment: @AlexanderTumanin it's the LayoutParams. I'll update my Answer.

Comment: thanks @tynn! Your last suggestion works for my third case! But it doesn't work for other cases, but then I can just set different layouts for different cases. Anyways, your suggestion is only one which works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change this:

```
    actionBar.setCustomView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null),
new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
    ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    Gravity.CENTER));
```

to this:

```
    actionBar.setCustomView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null),
new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: yes, in this case the title is not centered in the view with only left button too